# Can anti-vaxers be sued for medical malpractice?

Tags: medical

Vaccine stuff has been in the news lately.
It occurred to me that telling people not to get vaccinated could constitute medical advice.

Here is my question: if someone tells you not to get vaccinated, and then you get really sick with something you could have been vaccinated against: can you sue them?
If so: why do I keep hearing about "anti-vax communities" and "anti-vax propaganda"?  Why haven't these people been sued out of existence?

(this does not affect me personally; I have been vaccinated and I am not sick)

Comment: Its really that it is free speech. If you tell me the sky is purple, I can't sue you can I?

Comment: @Putvi I don't think that freedom of speech is applicable in this situation, I believe the OP is trying to find out if you can sue someone for giving you a serious illness if they could have taken steps to prevent it, and were knowable that they were carrying that illness.

Comment: We as a community need to know the location that this question applies to, so we can look up the laws for that area. For example: in the United States you can be tried in both civil and criminal court if you knowingly transmit HIV (Aids) to someone else without them knowing, but recently, in California laws have been passed so you no longer have to notify the other party before taking part in a sexual activity. Knowing what country it takes place in isn't always enough, to answer this question we need to know a specific location.

Comment: I think you want to be asking about unauthorized practice of medicine or practice of medicine without a license.  As others have noted, only a licensed medical practitioner can be liable for medical malpractice.

Comment: @phoog I think he just means people in general.

Comment: @Putvi exactly.  And people in general cannot practice medicine because they are not licensed to do so.

Comment: He isn't saying they can practice medicine. He is saying the things they say and do make others sick.

Comment: @Putvi the question concerns the idea "that telling people not to get vaccinated could constitute medical advice."  It seems to me that a good answer ought to discuss the conditions under which it would as well as those under which it would not.  If an anti-vaxxer sets up an office and examines people and then advises them to avoid vaccines, that person is probably liable criminally, and presumably also civilly if there is some harm.  If someone tells you "at a cocktail party" to avoid vaccines, there is probably no liability.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I don't feel that he is talking about people setting up an office. I think he is talking about people discussing this for political reasons.

Comment: A good parallel that the OP is trying to see whether it applies here is the fact that in many jurisdictions it is illegal to give *legal* advice if you are not a legal professional - some jurisdictions may have a similar restriction on medical advice.

Comment: Vaccines are generally exempt from the usual testing requirements expected from other drugs, so...

Comment: "_some jurisdictions may have a similar restriction on medical advice_" That would be both a violation of free speech and absolutely unenforceable and silly, as even "you are already drunk, it's bad for you to drink even more" could be illegal.

Comment: So which vaccines have proven benefits? Where? Since when is measles an horrible, horrible disease? (It was essentially a joke in the 60ties.)

Comment: @User37849012643, you misinterpreted the question. Knowing you are ill and transmitting that disease to another person without warning them you are ill is completely different than expressing an opinion about a vaccine and having another person agree with you and act, (or not) according to that belief. The two issues aren't even close to being similar.

Comment: @MichaelHall After review I think you might be right. I still stand by the point that more information about the specific jurisdiction was required to fully answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Merely encouraging people not to vaccinate via educational and political communication without purporting to provide individualized medical advice is probably not the practice of medicine and protected by the First Amendment's protections for freedom of speech, rather than constituting medical malpractice.

Also, many anti-vax individuals (I couldn't quote a percentage) do so out of religious conviction and are protected not just by the freedom of speech in the First Amendment, but also by the free exercise component of the freedom of religion under the First Amendment. Generally speaking, it is harder to find a legal grounds for disregarding the free exercise of religion than it is to find a legal basis to regulate otherwise free speech.

For example, commercial speech is subject to more rigorous regulation than private political and educational speech, which is why there are no private businesses taking anti-vax positions in their advertising.

The theory is that courts are not in a good position to make general determinations of the truth of policy positions or statements about general truths as opposed to what happened in a particular transaction or occurrence. This is in part because a ruling by the right court at the right time can preclude the correctness of its determination from being revisited indefinitely and from time to time, accepted conventional wisdom and scientific consensus at one time are revealed later on to have been wrong with more discussion and investigation. I think that this is unlikely to be the case in the vaccination area, but the whole point of the First Amendment's protection of these kinds of issues is that we can't know in advance what will continue to be widely accepted and what will turn out to be mistaken.

But, if someone in a medical diagnosis and treatment profession (e.g. M.D., D.O., physician's assistant, or nurse), were to advise a patient in a capacity as a medical care provider not to vaccinate, and as a result that person's child got sick from a disease that vaccination could have prevented, there probably would be medical malpractice liability.

A somewhat similar issue arises when health insurance companies or government agencies set rules on providing care. In those cases, it isn't uncommon to have a physician or other medical professional placed on a committee or in an office such as medical director, with that person making the call and exposed to liability although not in the same way as a treating medical professional. A [case about a month ago](https://washparkprophet.blogspot.com/2019/03/these-practices-by-former-health.html) found malpractice by an insurance company's medical director (the company was United Health) to be a huge liability for both the medical director and the insurance company.

Comment: I don't mean to criticize, but nursing malpractice is normally when a nurse preforms some procedure wrong and not giving only wrong advice since advice is supposed to stem from a doctor. https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/nursing-malpractice-30076.html

Comment: @Putvi it is generally malpractice for a nurse to give advice at all when the nurse doesn't have the authority to do so (leaving only causation and damages which limits suits to cases when the advice is bad), and some nurses (e.g. nurse practitioners) have diagnostic authority in their specialty. It isn't uncommon for vaccination to be handled almost entirely by nurses in some jurisdictions.

Comment: @Putvi registered nurses can and do provide advice (as do physiotherapists, occupational therapists, doctors etc.) and are subject to the same consequences for bad advice.

Comment: Surely there is some threshold with regard to the unlicensed or unauthorized practice of medicine that someone who is not a medical professional might cross in "telling [someone] not to get vaccinated."

Comment: @phoog While medical professionals have liability for their malpractice, unauthorized practice of medicine is a thing and basically involves holding oneself out to be a medical professional when you aren't and/or providing individualized advice in a provider-patient type relationship without a license to do so. I've seen a notable case involving a self-proclaimed naturopath. The distinction is similar to that for unauthorized practice of law.

Comment: Right, so my point is that an anti-vaxxer (not in possession of a medical license) who tries to discourage people from getting vaccinated by purporting to assess their medical condition and then giving individualized advice against vaccination would potentially be liable.  In other words, I'm thinking of cases that do not fall within the qualification in your first paragraph.

Comment: @phoog Yes, something like that might be unauthorized practice of medicine and also give rise to liability if not treated as a religious pastor-parishioner interaction, and harm results. Proving causation might be difficult however since one could argue that the person taking the advice had other sources of information that were ignored.

Comment: @phoog Fixed it.

Comment: "which is why there are no private businesses taking anti-vax positions in their advertising." I'm sure that there are companies offering "alternative medicine" that make anti-vaccine argument in their advertisements.

Comment: @ohwilleke yeah, I didn't mean nurses never give advice.

Comment: @Acccumulation Making a medical claim in connection with offering "alternative medicine" is contrary to FDA regulations and I've seen pretty high levels of compliance with that requirement. Of course, not every one store operation in a small town or Internet retailer is obeying the law, just as it is certainly true that people steal cars, rob banks, and sell heroin every day which is illegal. "Criminals" aren't the only ones who break the law, either, many businesses violate tax laws, and many illegally discriminate in hiring every day. But the law exists, even if it's often broken.

Comment: The bad medical advice case could only be plausible if vaccines usefulness was proven instead of just assumed, based on the assumption that it would be unethical to wait for real evidence that vaccines are beneficial over life, which could mean delaying widespread use of these drugs by decades, as the effect is alleged over long time scale (the measles vaccine is intended to protect adults more than children where measles is considered almost always benign).

Answer (score 0):

This would not even be a case of medical malpractice, unless this person was a licensed mefical professional.

If they misrepresented themselves as a medical professional, other laws might allow you to recover damages.

But otherwise, their words are honest opinions afforded full First Amendment protection.

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't sue them because you made the choice. If they forced you to do something and you are harmed, you can sue then.

Stating an opinion is free speech, even if the opinion is wrong.

Malpractice is when a doctor messes up. If the person giving you advice is not a doctor, he or she is not licensed to practice and therefore can not commit malpractice since he or she was never authorized to practice.

Here is an overview of what normally constitutes malpractice: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/medical-malpractice-basics-29855.html

> > A doctor-patient relationship existed. You must show that you had a physician-patient relationship with the doctor you are suing -- this means you hired the doctor and the doctor agreed to be hired.

Comment: The OP has misidentified the offense; the question does not concern malpractice, but unauthorized practice of medicine.  Nothing presented here suggests that the person offering the advice would be unable to be prosecuted for, or sued for civil liability arising from, that.

Comment: @phoog so you down vote me, but the answer above saying the same thing is fine? Lol

Comment: I had intended to raise the same issue in a comment on the other answer, but I must have fallen asleep before doing so.  I have now done it, so thank you for reminding me.  The main reason for the downvote, however, is that there are limits to free speech, and giving professional advice when not qualified to do so is among them.  The other answer qualified the free speech analysis with "via educational and political communication without purporting to provide individualized medical advice."

Comment: As quoted in my answer, you are not giving professional advice if you are not a doctor or other licensed professional.

Comment: That's not what the quote in your answer says.  It says that for a doctor to be liable for malpractice, there must be a doctor-patient relationship.  If what you said were true, then people accused of practicing medicine without a license would be able to defend themselves by claiming freedom of speech under the first amendment, which would be an absurd result.

Comment: No, the quote in my answer says a "doctor patient relationship" must exist for malpractice. Practicing medicine without a license is a crime. Giving advice is free speech.

Comment: Giving advice and practicing without a license are not the same thing. You can tell people they may need a band aid before, that's advice. You can't preform a surgery on people.

Comment: @phoog "_people accused of practicing medicine without a license would be able to defend themselves by claiming freedom of speech under the first amendment, which would be an absurd result_" I think that's an entirely reasonable defense, and other basic rights could be asserted, unless you assume that medical regs trump the Bill of Rights (which seems to be the default position).

Comment: @curiousguy licensing requirements generally impinge on one right or another, and that's entirely as it should be.  No right is absolute.

Comment: @phoog I don't think licencing is constitutional either.

Comment: @curiousguy then I'm glad you're not in charge.